# Add data labels to bar chart in Dashboard Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, performancepoint

I am trying to add data labels to a stacked bar chart in Dashboard Designer from cube data. The labels appear in the legend but I need it to be part of the bars themeselves. The labels appear when I hover over the bar but what I would like to know is how to have that information display in the bar itself. Is there anyway to do this?